# tcl error in set nf[open out.nam w]

Tags: tcl, ns2

the following code

```
#Create a simulator object
set ns [new Simulator]
#Open the nam trace file
set nf[open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf
#Define a 'finish' procedure
proc finish {} {
global ns nf
$ns flush-trace
#Close the trace file
close $nf
#Execute namon the trace file
exec nam–a out.nam&
exit 0
}
#Create two nodes
set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
#Create a duplex link between the nodes
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 1Mb 10ms DropTail
#Call the finish procedure after 5 seconds of simulation time
$ns at 5.0 "finish"
#Run the simulation
$ns run
```

produces this error

```
can't read "nffile5": no such variable
    while executing
"set nf[open out.nam w]"
    (file "Desktop/sample.tcl" line 4)
```

it is my first time in tcl. so what is the problem.
i just run this by this statement: > ns sample.tcl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a space after the variable name:

```
set nf [open out.nam w]
```

Tcl is very dependent on proper use of whitespace. The entire language can be described in 12 rules, listed [here](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm). Rule 3: "Words of a command are separated by white space (except for newlines, which are command separators)."

What was actually happening in your script:

- Tcl breaks the command into 2 words: the command `set` and the argument `nf[open out.nam w]`
- the command in brackets is executed and the result (the filehandle name returned is `file5`) is substituted.
- the `set` command is executed with its one argument, `nffile5`

  - when given a single argument, the set command will return the value of the given variable.
  - since you never assigned a variable by that name, `set` returns an error.